# How to read text from Captcha in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am having Captcha like 3+1= along with text boxes. I have to read the int values and enter the result in textboxes using SendKeys. I am able to capture the whole Capture image but I want to separate the each texts to add the numbers. How is it possible??

Can anyone please tell me??

Comment: Main purpose to add captcha is to remove these automated intrusions to the system! If you are testing an internal application, please ask development team to disabled those for testing purposes. And, if you are testing captcha, testing needs to done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha meant for avoiding automated form submissions, if you are testing for the site, you can have a setting in the quality testing server to serve a specific captcha and use sendkey to send back

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver is not supporting captcha.

While captcha is existing for the same reason so no one can use robot on the website.

You have to ask team to provide you special environment where they bypass the captcha functionality or ask your development team to expose the captcha values on DOM also so you can retrieve the value and then perform actions accordingly

Hope it will help you :)